# How do I make my image node jump when I tap the screen?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, sprite-kit

I am new to Xcode and currently in the process of learning swiftUI and SpriteKit.

I have started creating my game app in the GameScene.SKS section of Xcode and I'm trying to figure out how to get my character to jump when I click the screen in the simulator?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is general and not specific, it is highly unlikely, that anyone will come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the node in the `.sks` file, and reference it in code.

1. Create your sprite or type of node in the scene.
2. In the top-right of the image below, you can see I have named the sprite `red-square`. You will need to reference this later on.

[image]

3. In your `GameScene` class, write the following code replacing the node name with yours:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let redSquare = childNode(withName: "red-square") {
        redSquare.position = CGPoint(
            x: .random(in: frame.minX ... frame.maxX),
            y: .random(in: frame.minY ... frame.maxY)
        )
    }
}
```

Now, every time you tap anywhere in the scene, the red square will randomly go to a new position.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have copied this into my code and changed the name to my character. However, I'm receiving a few errors, "Cannot find childNode in scope" & "Cannot find frame in scope".

Comment: @DamianDunn Is this in you game scene class? Should be something like `class GameScene: SKScene { … }`?

Comment: Yes it is in the game scene.

Comment: @DamianDunn Well `SKScene` conforms to `SKNode`, therefore has a `frame` property and `childNode(withName:)` method. Without more information, I can't tell you why you get those errors. Try clean the project with cmd+shift+K, try rebuild, and if that doesn't work that's a different question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have been editing it all in GameViewController!

Comment: @DamianDunn Ah, that's why you didn't get an error when overriding too! Because the method is from `NSResponder` (I believe)